# Managed properties in display templates giving null

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, search-results, enterprise-search, display-template

I created custom display template for ms word documents, I'm able to get values like Path,SPSiteURL, ServerRedirectURL..etc, but when when i try to access 'Site' im getting null in it, I'm trying to get the site url.

here is the managed properties maapping in my display template

```
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Title':'Title','Path':'Path','Description':'Description','EditorOWSUSER':'EditorOWSUSER','LastModifiedTime':'LastModifiedTime','CollapsingStatus':'CollapsingStatus','DocId':'DocId','HitHighlightedSummary':'HitHighlightedSummary','HitHighlightedProperties':'HitHighlightedProperties','FileExtension':'FileExtension','ViewsLifeTime':'ViewsLifeTime','ParentLink':'ParentLink','FileType':'FileType','IsContainer':'IsContainer','SecondaryFileExtension':'SecondaryFileExtension','DisplayAuthor':'DisplayAuthor','ServerRedirectedURL':'ServerRedirectedURL','SectionNames':'SectionNames','SectionIndexes':'SectionIndexes','ServerRedirectedEmbedURL':'ServerRedirectedEmbedURL','ServerRedirectedPreviewURL':'ServerRedirectedPreviewURL','RefinableString15':'RefinableString15','RefinableString19':'RefinableString19','RefinableString07':'RefinableString07','ListID':'ListID','ListItemID':'ListItemID','SPSiteURL':'SPSiteURL','ContactName':'ContactName','RefinableString22':'RefinableString22','Site':'Site'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
```

I'm getting values if I call  `ctx.CurrentItem.SPSiteURL , ctx.CurrentItem.ListID,ctx.CurrentItem.ListItemID` 
but  if I call  `ctx.CurrentItem.Site` I'm getting null value.

I'm trying to get Site Path

Comment: It is always easier to help you out if you add a code snippet :)

Comment: How is the Managed Property Site configured? Compared to SPSiteURL

Comment: Have you made Site yourself? What is Path giving you?

Comment: I checked the managed properties in my site collecion
SPSiteURL is mapped to ows_SPSiteURL but Site is not mapped to any crawled property

Comment: Well no wonder it returns nothing then ;)

Comment: No Site is an OOTB managed property

Comment: If you can not find a Crawled property containing what you need you will have to use the best matching one and maybee do some trimming

Comment: Then which property should I use to get Site Url

Comment: I would use SitePath and then trim it

Comment: I tried Many Managed properties(Path, ServerRedirectedUrl, ServerEmbedurl,serverredirectpreviewurl,parentlink) and tried to trim them by one slash or two slashes but the problem here is the site can can be in any depth(like sreddyb.sp.com/sites/consumersandbox/salescloud/subsite1/subsite2/subsite3/Documents),and the document may come from any subfolder(it can also have any depth like(sreddyb/sp.com/site/consumersandbox/salescloud/sales/Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/mydoc.docx)) So where should i do substring. The SitePath giving the path to the folder that contains the document

Comment: How can i know how many slashes i should remove

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10439/discussion-between-robert-lindgren-and-sekhar2815)